# Arrow particle simulation - arrows don't stick to the ground

Tags: particles

no matter how I set my collision plane, my arrow particle simulation doesn't work as intended - the arrows always slide a little bit over the surface, instead of sticking into it. I added a gif showing the issue, as well as the setting of my collision plane.

Do you please know how to make the arrows not slide, but remain stuck where they land?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file - thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check "die on hit" and "dead", then you will get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Amazing, that solved it! thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome